# Output for arithmetic progression series is incorrect in C

Tags: c

here is my homework:

[image: Homwork]

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   int firstTerm, commonDifference, numberOfTerms, arithmeticSeries, i;

   printf("Please enter the first term: ");
   scanf("%d", &firstTerm);

   printf("Please enter the common difference: ");
   scanf("%d", &commonDifference);

   printf("Please enter the number of terms: ");
   scanf("%d", &numberOfTerms);

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++) {

        apSeries = firstTerm, firstTerm + commonDifference, firstTerm + (commonDifference * 2), firstTerm + (commonDifference * 3);

        printf("The arithmetic progression series is: %d", arithmeticSeries);
    
    }
}
```

And this is my output. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

```
The arithmetic progression series is: 1The arithmetic progression ser
ies is: 1The arithmetic progression series is: 1The arithmetic progre
ssion series is: 1
```

Comment: `apSeries = firstTerm, firstTerm + commonDifference, firstTerm + (commonDifference * 2), firstTerm + (commonDifference * 3);` It looks like you don't know what the comma operator does in C.

Comment: And does this code even compile? `apSeries` is an undefined variable.

Comment: @kaylum yes, it's because I changed the variables just for this question but forgot to change all of them. Sorry!

Comment: You should end your printf with `\n` so everything isn't on one line.

Comment: @mmno It's hard to understand exactly what your issue is. Did you realize that you were using a comma operator here? There are no comments in your code, so it's hard to understand what your reasoning is. It won't help you much for me to show you how I  would solve this problem because there are so many different ways to solve it. The short answer is -- you can't just make something up and expect it to work. You need to learn what comma does in C and use it when, and only when, you need what it does.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He was trying to copy the example equation in the hint part of the assignment.

Comment: @Barmar Well spotted! What an irony that it's the hint that led him astray.

Comment: @Barmar yep, you're right! :) also, i'm a "she"

Comment: I'm old. In my day "mmno" was always a man's name. :)

Comment: @Barmar that's not my real name. this is a throwaway account bc I don't use SO that often.

Comment: It was a joke, it's obviously not a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the series is `firstTerm + i * commonDifference`. This is what the hint was trying to show you.

You can't just assign all of them at once like it shows, it was just demonstrating the arithmetic relationship.

```
    printf("The arithmetic progression series is:");
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++) {
        arithmeticSeries = firstTerm + i * commonDifference;
        printf(" %d", arithmeticSeries);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Or you could add `commonDi

Comment: It still didn't give my the answer I wanted since it prints out: The arithmetic progression series is: 1The arithmetic progression ser
ies is: 3The arithmetic progression series is: 5The arithmetic progre
ssion series is: 7

but it's better than the other one so i'll take it. Thank you!

Comment: That can't be the output of this code, I took the first part of the message out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Arithmetic Progression, you already know that the formula is :

> value of n-term = first no + (n-1)*common difference

From your code the printing part is fine meaning the user input part. Your main issue is the loop. So what I did was

```
for(i=1; i<=noOfTerms; i++) {
arithmeticSeries = firstTerm + ((i-1)*commonDifference);
prinf("The arithmetic progression series is: %d\n", arithmeticSeries);
}
```

The reason why I started from 1 is because based on arithmetic progression principle, let's say I started from 0, then your output will show

```
The arithmetic progression series is: -1
The arithmetic progression series is: 1
The arithmetic progression series is: 3
The arithmetic progression series is: 5
The arithmetic progression series is: 7
```

Not only the output is wrong, but also the number of outputs according to my loop. I started from 1 so as to get a positive number, Z+. So hence I the output is as follows:

```
The arithmetic progression series is: 1
The arithmetic progression series is: 3
The arithmetic progression series is: 5
The arithmetic progression series is: 7
```

I hope that answers your question. :)